# How to change select option text

Tags: javascript

[image]
When I set the has-empty-data=true attribute for the select tag, an empty option will be added to the list option. so how can I set the text for this empty option tag?

```
<select name="address[province]" title="{{ 'customer.addresses.province' | t }}" has-empty-data="true" data-default="{{ form.province }}" id="provinceExist"></select>
```

[image]
I tried doing this but it still doesn't work

```
document.getElementsByName('provinceExist').options[0].innerHTML = "Water";
```

Comment: you're `getElementByName` with param is the `id` right?

Comment: when I console.log, text "Water" did show but in the Elements tab it still can't show the text "Water"

Answer (score 1):

You need to used `getElementById` instead of `getElementByName` as your field have `id` called `provinceExist`:

Also, you need to add `ContentLoaded` event for change text or you need to create function to call on event happen. I have taken Content loaded event as an example.

```
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        document.getElementById("provinceExist").options[0].text = "Water";
    });
```

Here example select box:

```
<select name="address[province]" id="provinceExist">
  <option>Test</option>
  <option>Test1</option>
  <option>Test2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried doing but text 'Water' don't show in Select option

Comment: @user20942136 I have update my answer. please check it.

Comment: @user20942136 I have update my anwser again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the text property of the Option object:

```
document.getElementsByName('provinceExist').options[0] = new Option('Water', '');
```

You can also use the `innerHTML` property to set the text for the empty option tag, like this:

```
document.getElementsByName('provinceExist').options[0].innerHTML = 'Water';
```

`getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements, so you need to access the first element in the collection to be able to set the `innerHTML` or text property.

Comment: I tried doing but text 'Water' don't show in Select option. Please see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIiJn.png

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('address[province]').options[0].innerHTML = "Water";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByName('provinceExist').options[0].innerHTML = "Water";
```

or if you want to use the id you could use

```
document.getElementsById('provinceExist').options[0].innerHTML = "Water";
```

there's also another neatway instead of having to go through all this

```
<select>
<option hidden disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>


  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

this will show up `-- select an option --` and once you select something this option won't no longer exist and you won't be able to select it back/view it again

Comment: I tried doing but text 'Water' don't show in Select option. Please see picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5TtS.png